# Does a closed set not discrete have a limit point?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, analysis

**My Question**: Let $U\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ open and $A\subset U$ be a close set not discrete in $U$, then $A$ must have a limit point in $U$.

**Remark:** I do not know if the statement is true. I know that discrete closed sets do not have limit points, but I do not know if this may serve to prove the statement.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Pick $a \in A$. Pick a fundamental basis $U_\alpha$ of open sets at $a$.

Then since $A$ is not discrete, for each $\alpha$ you can find some $x_\alpha \in U_\alpha -\{a\}$.

Note that the proof works in any topological space.

Answer (score 0):

$A$ is discrete if for each $a\in A$ there exists $r>0$ such that $B_r(a)\cap A=\{a\}$. By assumption, this is not the case. Hence there exists $a\in A$ such that for all $r>0$, $B_r(a)\cap A$ contains points $\ne a$ from $A$. Pick $a_n\in B_{1/n}r(a)\cap (A\setminus\{a\}$. Then $a_n\to a$.